# In Unity, how to add animation when flying, and fall crash

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a simple game when instantiated monsters are waling towards left in linear field, and stopping them by throwing(drag-drop) them up(y-axis).
What I want to do is;
Q1. add animator when the clicked monster is flying; and
Q2. add a fall crash animator when it exactly reaches the ground..

I think I can figure q1. by using if(transform.position.y > @){SetTrigger}
but I have no idea, how to solve q2....

Please help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! You have to provide some code showing what you tried so far. We cannot do your work for you, only help you if you get stuck. This is the reason that people are downvoting your post.

Answer (score 0):

To solve q2 you could simply write a script that is attached to the enemies. In that script you then can check for a Collider hit with the ground. When the Object is flying you can set a flag for that and test for it in the function.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    if(collision.collider.tag == "Ground") {
        if (wasDraggedByPlayerAndHadFallAnimation) {
            //Trigger death animation here
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground")
        {
            if (isFlying == true)
            {
                nowHP = -100;
                Splashanim.SetTrigger("SplashedTrigger");
                isFlying = false;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Thanks, I understood how its working! But, it is not working.. could u help me out?
Also,  I put the same script in instantiated monster,  so it decreases the Hp * # of monsters in field.,,
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground")
        {
            if (isFlying == true)
            {
                Debug.Log("Crashed");
                nowHP = -100;
                Splashanim.SetTrigger("SplashedTrigger");
                isFlying = false;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Thank you! I solved it by using your code in the Ground script!